# Get recommendations based on artists of other users

Tags: last.fm

I like looking at the library of my friends, but most of the artists that we have in our library are the same. Is there a possibility to get a list of artists that are not in my library? Or even a list of recommended artists, based on another user's library?

I am looking for this function, but I can't find a button on the profile pages of other users.